# Create xsd.Element with specific namespace naming in Zeep

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

I'm trying to create a custom SOAP header element using Zeep which uses several namespaces. When doing so, They are named `ns0`, `ns1` and so on. For example:

```py
usernametoken_header = xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}UsernameToken', xsd.ComplexType([
    xsd.Attribute('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Id', xsd.String()),
    xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Username', xsd.String()),
    xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Password', xsd.String())
    ]))
```

Will have `ns0` for what is `wsse`, and `ns1` for what is `wsu`. Now I want to rename them to those values, but **without repositioning the namespace declaration**. I also don't want to use `UsernameToken`. I am aware of the option to do:

```py
client.set_ns_prefix('wsse', "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
```

But this repositions the namespace declaration from the first child that uses it, up to the root node. I do not want such repositioning. Is there any way to do a in-place renaming of the namespace?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also don't want to use `UsernameToken`." ? Also, are you trying to format a header for the zeep client to send to or receive from a SOAP service?